# For any given parameters, does there always exist a quantum code which saturates the Quantum Hamming Bound?

Tags: error-correction

We know that the Quantum Hamming Bound is as follows:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^t 3^j {n\choose j} \leq 2^{n-k}$$

where

- $n$ is the number of physical qubits,
- $k$ is the number of logical qubits,
- $t$ is the maximum weight for which all errors are correctable.

For any given $t$ and $k$, should there always exist of code with $n$ physical qubits which saturates this bound? How can we go about trying to prove/disprove this in a more formal manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No. There exist $t$ and $k$ for which the Quantum Hamming Bound (QHB) cannot be saturated by any block size $n$.

### Constraint on block size $n$

Consider the simplest case of $t=1$ in which the QHB takes the form
$$
\sum_{j=0}^t3^j {n\choose j}=1+3n\leqslant 2^{n-k}\tag1
$$
or equivalently
$$
k\leqslant n-\log_2(1+3n).\tag2
$$
The inequality can only be saturated by integer values of $k$ and $n$ if $\log_2(1+3n)$ is an integer. This happens if and only if the binary representation of $n$ takes the form$^1$
$$
10101\dots 101\tag3
$$
i.e. if and only if $n\in F$ where $F:=\{1,5,21,85,\dots\}$ is the set of sums of consecutive powers of four beginning with $4^0=1$.

Thus, we have a necessary condition for a code $[\![n,k,3]\!]$ to saturate QHB: it must be the case that $n\in F$.

### Constraint on number $k$ of encoded qubits

Define $f(x):=x-\log_2(1+3x)$ and let $f[F]$ denote the image of $F$ under $f$. We can strengthen the above necessary condition for a code $[\![n,k,3]\!]$ to saturate QHB as follows: it must be the case that $n\in F$ and $k=f(n)$. In particular, it must be the case that $k\in f[F]$.

By calculus, $f$ is strictly increasing on positive integers$^2$. Moreover, evaluating $f$ on the first few elements of $F$, we find
$$
f(1)=-1, f(5)=1, f(21)=15, f(85)=77.\tag4
$$
Clearly, there are gaps, so $\mathbb{Z}_+\setminus f[F]$ is non-empty.

### Conclusion

For $t=1$ and any $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+\setminus f[F]$ there exists no $n$ saturating the Quantum Hamming Bound.

---

<sup>$^1$ Fun exercise.

$^2$ The derivative of $f(x)$ has a single root at $x_*=\frac{3-\ln2}{3\ln2}\approx1.1$ and is positive for $x>x_*$, so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>x_*$. However, $f(1)=-1<2-\log_27=f(2)$, so $f(x)$ is in fact strictly increasing on all positive integers.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Why not take the special case of $t=1,k=2$ (because we know $t=1,k=1$ has a solution). You are looking for an integer value of $n$ such that
$$
1+3n=2^{n-2}.
$$
I claim there is not such solution. One way to see this is to define $f(n)=1+3n-2^{n-2}$. We can work out a few values

| n | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f(n) | 8 | 9 | 8 | 3 | -10 |

So, no solution $f(n)=0$ for those values of $n$. But for $n>4$, $f(n)$ is a decreasing function ($\frac{df}{dn}=3-2^{n-2}\log2$), so it only becomes more negative for larger values of $n$, so there cannot be a solution.